# Do artificial turf fields lead to more injuries than grass fields?

Tags: nfl, injuries

In the NFL, [some teams play on artificial turf and others play on real grass.](https://www.nbcsports.com/washington/football-team/which-nfl-stadiums-have-artificial-turf-vs-real-grass)

While injuries happen throughout the league, anecdotally speaking, it seems like more injuries, especially ACL injuries, take place on artificial turf. [Some players](https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/cooper-kupp-says-nfl-should-not-play-games-on-turf-hands-down-we-should-be-playing-on-grass/) expressed their concerns about playing on turf and prefer to play on grass.

Is there data that confirms the number of injuries that take place on grass vs. turf?

Comment: I'm not sure what sport is being considered here. But major football pitches in Europe are nowadays a hybrid of artificial and natural grass. Certainly the ones you are seeing in the World Cup will be a mixture. Though the man showing us around Old Trafford, did indicate that the artificial component was in a significant minority. I believe the "astra-turf" pitches do cause injury problems such as skin burns, when sliding etc.

Answer (score 4):

According to [data from IQVIA](https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/34982032/nfl-data-shows-recent-injury-rates-same-grass-artificial-turf), a third-party company hired by the NFL and NFLPA, non-contact lower extremity injury rates to football players in 2021 were similar on artificial turf vs. grass.

In 2019, incidents on turf were higher than grass (0.048 incidences per 100 vs. 0.036 incidences per 100) however since those rates have converged.

Comment: Are you talking about football or football? Because in the game that Americans call football, are the players not fully clothed? That presumably reduces the incidence of skin burns.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2022/11/14/research-shows-statistically-significant-higher-risk-of-lower-extremity-injuries-on-slit-film-turf/) from Pro Football Talk, data shows “slit-film has a statistically significant higher risk of LEX [lower extremity] injury than the League average,” and “models suggest there are 2-3 more non-contact lower extremity injuries per season per stadium on slit film surfaces than other types of synthetic turf fields.”